# After applying for a CiviCRM account, how long does it take to approve?

Tags: community

We have applied for a CiviCRM account and wondering how long it would take to approve the application?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean an account with civicrm.org then usually not so long. I have pinged someone on chat.civicrm.org to try and resolve this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Accounts are manually approved (we used to get a lot of spam). It can take up to 1 or 2 working days. In some cases, account requests can get flagged as spam. You can also reach us on the chat (https://chat.civicrm.org). You can ping @bgm or @josh.

Comment: I thought the issue was that without their account they couldn't get on chat either - or have i misunderstood

Comment: Accounts on chat are on their own system, and usually no delay.